# Disable mapping for a specific field using an Index Template Elasticsearch 6.8

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, efk

I have an EFK pipeline set up. Everyday a new index is created using the logstash-* prefix. Every time a new field is sent by Fluentd, the field is added to the index pattern logstash-*. I'm trying to create an index template that will disable indexing on a specific field when an index is created. I got this to work in ES 7.1 using the PUT below:

```
PUT _template/logstash-test
{
  "index_patterns": ["logstash-*"],
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
          "params" : {
            "path_match" : "params",
            "mapping" : {
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

However when I try this on Elasticsearch 6.8 I get the following error:

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Malformed [mappings] section for type [dynamic_templates], should include an inner object describing the mapping"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little different in Elasticsearch 6.X as it had mapping types, which is [not used anymore](https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch).

Try something like this:

```
PUT _template/logstash-test
{
    "index_patterns": ["logstash-*"],
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "dynamic_templates" : [
                {
                    "params" : {
                        "path_match" : "params",
                        "mapping" : {
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If your index has a different custom type and is not using the `_doc` type, you should use that in the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The custom type here was fluentd.